# Error occuring in smtp email verification while hosting it on server (LIVE)

Tags: php, codeigniter, live, email-verification

Currently website is already hosted in wordpress PHP. Implementing in Codeigniter PHP to expand the different module in existing website there is a quiz model section. Implementing that quiz model and before you proceed to play you should login or register - When user register and click on the signup it encountered error..It will send an email verification link to your email id. But it showing error

```
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465
(Connection refused)
```

Code is running and working properly on localhost but not when I host it on live

you can go check the [link live](http://www.sarvashikshan.com/quiz/index.php/Questions/sign_up)

Model File

```
public function sendEmail($receiver){
    $from = "";    //senders email address
    $subject = 'Verify email address';  //email subject

    //sending confirmEmail($receiver) function calling link to the user, 
inside message body
    $message = 'Dear User,<br><br> Please click on the below activation link 
 to verify your email address<br><br>
 <ahref=\'http://www.localhost/codeigniter/index.php/
Signup_Controller/confirmEail/'
 .md5($receiver).'\'>http://www.localhost/codeigniter/index.php/
Signup_Controller/confirmEmail/'. md5($receiver) .'</a><br><br>Thanks';



    //config email settings
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_user'] = $from;
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '';  //sender's password
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = 'TRUE';
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; 

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    //send email
    $this->email->from($from);
    $this->email->to($receiver);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);

    if($this->email->send()){
        //for testing
        echo "Check your email";
        return true;
    }else{
        echo "email send failed";
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: show your code for sending email

Comment: @YadhuBabu please check

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you have not enabled ssl in your PHP Configuration. 
Check your **ssl** status in your PHP info ? If it's not enabled then in your `php.ini` file make these changes :

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

change it to

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Restart your apache server once, you make these changed.
On you Cpanel check the PHPINFO and verify the changes have been done successfully

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gmail SMTP mail then Go to your Gmail account and allow less secure apps under connected apps and sites

```
$config['smtp_user'] = 'example@gmail.com'; //your SMTP username
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'gmail_log_in_password';  //your SMTP password
```

Change

```
$config['charset'] => 'iso-8859-1';
```

to

```
$config['charset'] => 'utf-8';
```

and

```
$this->load->library('email',$config);
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

to

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
```